# ActiveAdmin updating filter collection (reset_filters!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I see that [ActiveAdmin::Filters::ResourceExtension defines reset_filters!](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/filters/resource_extension.rb?source=cc#L69), but I don't know where this should be called. When I create new records in active admin, I want the filters to be reset.

Example: I have a Post model and Tag model. Posts have many Tags. When I create a new Tag and tag a Post with that new tag, the filter on the Posts ActiveAdmin page doesn't update - it just lists the tags that existed previously and does not include the new tag in the filters.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that's because you have filters like this:

```
filter :foo, as: :select, collection: Foo.where(bar: 'baz')
```

But what you need is this:

```
filter :foo, as: :select, collection: proc{ Foo.where(bar: 'baz') }
```

Also, for posterity: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2465

Comment: I got an error passing the collection as a lambda, but using a Proc {...} worked just fine.

Comment: Is it possible that this does not work for `input`  in the form?